# Use HTML5 cache manifest to improve performance?

Tags: performance, html, cache-manifest

i was reading [Dive into HTML5: Offline web apps: Cache manifest](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/offline.html#manifest) when i got an idea. can i use it (HTML5 Cache Manifest) to cache files (eg. CSS/JS/Images/etc) for offline capability. but also for performance. user wont need to load those files when they visit your site again? or will it (files cached by cache manifest) work only in offline mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if the browser supports offline then it will cache all the files listed in the manifest and only update them when you change the manifest.  Last year someone demonstrated a technique based on the manifest to [overcome the 15K per item limit of the iPhone cache](http://www.phpied.com/iphone-caching/).

Comment: "*only update them when you change the manifest*" what abt if i am online and the file is updated on server? will it be checked?

Comment: @jiewmeng Not unless you also update the manifest file at the same time.